# Python / sqlite - Only committing last if statement

Tags: python, sqlite, commit

In the code below the only commit that actually shows up in the DB is the last 'idn' found. The idn is just an identifying number to count how many set top boxes there are per customer. So if idn 1,2 and 3 all exist it only writes 3 to the DB when it should right 1,2 and 3.  If idn 1 is the only one to exist, then it gets written.  Thanks for your help!

```
    if "STBSINFO||" in line:
        head, sep, tail = line.partition('STBSINFO||')
        idn = idn + 1
        if "|" in tail:
            head, sep, tail = tail.partition('|')
            #Creates the mac address variable from the partition
            mac = head                                    
            if "|" in tail:
                head, sep, tail = tail.partition('|')
                #Gathers the IP of the given set top box
                stbip = head
                if idn == 1:
                    cursor.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO packages (cid, mstb1) VALUES (?,?)", (cid, stbip))
                    conn.commit()
                elif idn == 2:
                    cursor.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO packages (cid, mstb2) VALUES (?,?)", (cid, stbip))
                    conn.commit()
                elif idn == 3:
                    cursor.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO packages (cid, mstb3) VALUES (?,?)", (cid, stbip))
                    conn.commit()
                elif idn == 4:
                    cursor.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO packages (cid, mstb4) VALUES (?,?)", (cid, stbip))
                    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not insert-or-replace-ing `1`, then insert-or-replace-ing `2` (which replaces `1`), then insert-or-replace-ing `3` (which replaces `2`)? If you don't know… first of all, why are you using `INSERT OR REPLACE` if you don't want to replace values; second of all, please post the schema for the `packages` table so someone else can figure it out for you.

Comment: I'm using INSERT OR REPLACE because the info could change from month to month.  I get an output file from an old system and then using this python program make sense of it.  If there's a better way I am open to it.  Why would the INSERT OR REPLACE on 2 replace 1? They are different columns in the table.  This is what I use to create the table:     cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE packages(cid TEXT, mstb1 TEXT, mstb2 TEXT, mstb3 TEXT, mstb4 TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (cid))

Comment: I don't think you understand what `INSERT OR REPLACE` does. It inserts a brand new row, completely replacing any conflicting row with your new row. It does not change values in an existing row. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `cid` is a primary key, or has some other uniqueness constraint on it—as in your example—you cannot have multiple rows with the same `cid`. So, when you `INSERT OR REPLACE` a row with the same `cid` as the previous one, it will just replace the previous row.

For example:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE packages (cid PRIMARY KEY, mstb1, mstb2, mstb3, mstb4);
sqlite> INSERT INTO packages (cid, mstb1) values (1, 1);
sqlite> INSERT OR REPLACE INTO packages (cid, mstb2) values (1, 2);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM packages;
cid|mstb1|mstb2|mstb3|mstb4
1||2||
```

And this is exactly what happens in your program. You insert the row `1|1|||`, then you replace it with the row `1||2||`, then you replace it with the row `1|||3|`. It's not that only one row is being written, it's that each row replaces the one before it, so in the end, you just have whichever one you wrote last.

---

If you were trying to update the row, you use an `UPDATE` statement for that, not an `INSERT OR REPLACE`:

```
sqlite> UPDATE packages SET mstb1=1 WHERE cid=1;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM packages;
cid|mstb1|mstb2|mstb3|mstb4
1|1|2||
```

If you were trying to create two separate rows, then you've set your schema up wrong; `cid` can't be a unique key if you want two different rows with the same `cid`. Maybe you want the set of all five columns to be a key in that case?

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE packages (cid NOT NULL, mstb1, mstb2, mstb3, mstb4, PRIMARY KEY(cid, mstb1, mstb2, mstb3, mstb4));
sqlite> INSERT INTO packages (cid, mstb1) values (1, 1);
sqlite> INSERT INTO packages (cid, mstb2) values (1, 2);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM packages;
cid|mstb1|mstb2|mstb3|mstb4
1|1|||
1||2||
```

---

The documentation on [`INSERT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html), [`ON CONFLICT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html), and [`UPDATE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) explains things in more detail.

However, I think you need a basic tutorial on SQL databases before the reference docs will make much sense.

Comment: I don't want multiple rows with the same cid.  I want each row to have a cid and then a variable number of mstbs, up to 4.  So your last example is more what I want.  My knowledge of SQL is pretty limited.  I'm just learning as I go.

Comment: I suspect what you _really_ want is to normalize your data model: to have a table of `packages` that just has the `cid`, with a one-to-many relation to a table of `package_whatevers` that has `cid, mstbid, value`, with the first two columns being a unique primary key. Wikipedia has a [good article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), but really you're going to need to find a tutorial on relational databases.

Comment: I will research that and see what I can learn.  Currently when I switch from INSERT OR REPLACE to INSERT I get this error 'IntegrityError: column cid is not unique'

Comment: @user2716271: Well, yeah, that's the point. You've designed a table that can only have one row with the same `cid`. If you try to `INSERT`  a row with the same `cid`, it will fail. If you try to `INSERT OR REPLACE` a row with the same `cid`, it will delete the old row so it can insert the new one. That's what those statements are supposed to do. If you want to update an existing row, neither one can do that, which is why there's a separate `UPDATE` statement. Which I explained in my answer.

Comment: Thanks sooo much for your help.  Not only do I have it working now but I feel I understand these SQL statements better.  Thanks again!